# not able to open java application on mozilla

Tags: java, mozilla, centos

I have centos 5.3 with Mozilla Firefox 3.5.5 and installed java jre-1.6.0_14 but when i open any web page which include java mozilla ask me that required package is missing. I have also enabled java in mozilla. What else i can check to fix this.

I opened http://www.java.com/en/download/help/testvm.xml to test my java and i got a popup window for missing plugins. The only missing plugin it show is java runtime environment.

Comment: are you able to use java from command lines, i.e. any java applicaton?

Comment: Please include the exact error message (don't just say "something about a required package missing"). The more details you provide, the better people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [Using the Java plugin with Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using+the+Java+plugin+with+Firefox).

This will give you brief information about:

```
   * Testing Java
   * Enabling Java
   * Other software that may block Java
   * Installing or updating Java
   * Manual install or update
   * Updates
   * Troubleshooting
   * Issues or problems related to Java
   * Additional resources
```